# Synchronizing ASC File Reading with Video Frames without having any common value

Tags: c#, vector, synchronization, avi

I have Vector ASC Log files and it's respective video files which are logged for same duration (lets say 5 minutes). Following is the Vector ASC File Format :

```
<timestamp>    <channelNumber>    <MsgID>    <Mode:Rx/Tx>   <dlc>    <data>
<timestamp>    <channelNumber>    <MsgID>    <Mode:Rx/Tx>   <dlc>    <data>
.
.
.
<timestamp>    <channelNumber>    <MsgID>    <Mode:Rx/Tx>   <dlc>    <data>
```

Video is getting logged in **`.avi`** format. While replaying I am loading both ASC file and it's respective video file.

> Problem is, how can I sync Vector ASC line data with Video frame. I want to
>   read ASC data line by line and show it on the gui along with it's
>   corresponding video frame.

Video files can be logged with different FPS values (30, 40 etc.).

Any lead would be very helpful. Thanks.